# how can I scan an Azure environment for ASR protected items using powershell

Tags: powershell

We would like to scan for ASR protected items in our azure tenant using Powershell or any other means . How can I achieve this

Checking from portal

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.